# deploying gae to development server stopped working

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin

I'm working through a test GAE Java project which was working fine but I decided to look at adding GWT to the same project.  I then decided to stick with the GAE stuff I was learning and decided to remove GWT.  The problem is I can't now deploy to the development server as it gives the following in the Eclipse console pane.  Anyone know please how I can reset appropriate settings to how my project had them originally?

> terminated test [Web Application] C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin\javaw.exe   Usage: 
>   [options]
>
> Options:  --help, -h                 Show this help message and exit. 
>   --server=SERVER            The server to use to determine the latest   -s SERVER                   SDK version.  --address=ADDRESS          The address of the interface on the local machine   -a ADDRESS
>   to bind to (or 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).  --port=PORT
>   The port number to bind to on the local machine.   -p PORT 
>   --sdk_root=DIR             Overrides where the SDK is located.  --disable_update_check     Disable the check for newer SDK versions.  --generated_dir=DIR        Set the directory where generated files are created.  --jvm_flag=FLAG            Pass FLAG as a JVM argument. May
>   be repeated to
>                                 supply multiple flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found my own answer through setting up a new dummy gae project and having a poke around, found that the 'Run As' > 'Run Configurations...' > '(x)= Arguments' > 'Program arguments' had an additional port defined prior to the rest of the argument beginning '--port=8888'. I removed the mention of '-codeServerPort 9997 ' and it now deploys to dev server and appears to be working as before.

eg

new dummy project: --port=8888 "C:\Users\tech1\SSD Storage\Eclipse Projects\workspace\dummy\war"

project that wouldn't deploy to dev server: -codeServerPort 9997 --port=8888 "C:\Users\tech1\SSD Storage\Eclipse Projects\workspace\test\war"

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and you know what, Workaround is just pretty simple.

I created one new appengine project with only one jsp in WAR and 'Run As' > 'Run Configurations...' >Server Tab -> Unchecked then checked Run Built-In server and then checked Automatically select any port.

Server started ..on some fishy 25334 port..i stopped that using red button on Console Terminal.

then i changed it back to 8888 and WHOA project Ran.... :)

Then i did the same with old project. deleted this new one and all is working as expected.